# JavaScript document write in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

This code below runs with jaavascript error in IE 8 browser after `window.open('','','width=200,height=100')` line of code gets executed. New window gets open but it runs with error "jQuery is undefined". Here I do not use jQuery at all, but sure, I use it all across the site.

```
var newWindow = window.open('','','width=200,height=100')                
newWindow.document.write(someHmtlAsString);
newWindow.document.close();
newWindow.focus();
```

Does anyone have suggestion why is this so, or is there some bug in IE (hack for IE) which would eliminate javascript error while page renders?

Thanks

Comment: In the window that you open, you need to make sure jQuery is included in the HTML of page.

Comment: what is the content of `someHTMLAsString`?

Comment: do you mean newWindow.document.write? And what is myWindow?

Comment: @Christophe I have just fix it, my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the source of new windows and iframes to `about:blank` if you want control over them.

You also want to use `newWindow.contentDocument || newWindow.contentWindow.document`
And it might be a good idea to `open()` the document before you `write()` to it.

**Update:** forgot this:
If you open the window about:blank, it needs time to load..
So you cannot write to it at once!!
So either check if it is loaded (onload), then have it write the source (I prefer this).
OR set timeout of about 50ms (usually) and then write to the new window/iframe.

also note that xhtml does not support `document.write`!!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `someHmtlAsString` that you insert contains some `<script>` tag that tries to use jQuery. Inspect its content and if that's the case, add tag to load jQuery to it or change code not to use it.